# Mathematics for Computer Science Prob. 2.6 Well Ordering Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, well-orders

### Problem

(From Mathematics for Computer Science (Lehman, Leighton, Meyers), Prob. 2.6)

> You are given a series of envelopes, respectively containing 1, 2, 4,
> ..., $2^m$ dollars. Define
>
> **Property** *m*: For any nonnegative integer less than $2^{m+1}$, there is a selection of envelopes whose contents add up to *exactly* that number of dollars.
>
> Use the Well Ordering Principle (WOP) to prove that Property *m* holds for all nonnegative integers *m*.
>
> *Hint*: Consider two cases: first, when the target number of dollars is less than $2^m$ and second, when the target number is at least $2^m$.

### Solution attempt

Let's refer to Property *m* as $P(m)$ to make things simpler.

Let $C$ be the following set:

$C = \{ m \mid \text{P(m) doesn't hold for } m\}$

Then, by the WOP, there is a smallest integer $m_0$ in $C$.

$P(m)$ holds for m = 0, since any nonnegative integer less than $2^{0+1} = 2$ can be represented with a selection of envelopes (the integer $0$ can be represented by a selection of no envelopes, and the integer $1$ can be represented with the envelope containing $1$). So, $m_0 > 0$.

Also, $P(m_0-1)$ holds (since $m_0-1 < m_0$), which means that all nonnegative integers less than $2^{m_0}$ can be represented by a selection of envelopes that contain up to $2^{m_0-1}$.

Since $P(m_0)$ is false, this means that there is a nonnegative integer $c$ less than $2^{m_0 + 1}$ such that $c$ can't be obtained by a selection of the envelopes $1$, $2$, $4$, ..., $2^{m_0}$.

From the above paragraph, we know that $c < 2^{m_0+1}$, and, from the fact that $P(m_0-1)$ holds, we know that $c \geq 2^{m_0}$. So:

$2^{m_0} \leq c < 2^{m_0+1}$

To show that there is a contradiction, there are two cases:

- If $c$ is even: Dividing the above inequality by 2, $2^{m_0-1} \leq c/2 < 2^{m_0}$. So, since $c/2$ is smaller than $2^{m_0}$, $P(c/2)$ holds and $c/2$ can be represented by a selection of envelopes. However, this means that $2(c/2) = c$ can also be represented as a selection of envelopes, which is a contradiction.
- If $c$ is odd: Subtracting 1 from the above inequality and dividing it by 2, $2^{m_0-1} - 1/2 \leq (c - 1)/2 < 2^{m_0} - 1/2$. Since $(c - 1)/2$ is smaller than $2^{m_0}$, $P((c - 1)/2)$ holds and $(c - 1)/2$ can be represented by a selection of envelopes. However, this means that $2((c - 1)/2) + 1 = c$ can also be represented as a selection of envelopes, which is a contradiction.

So, $C$ is empty and $P(m)$ holds for all nonnegative integers $m$.

I didn't use the provided hint in my solution attempt, which makes me think that there might be something incomplete about this attempt.
Is there anything missing from this proof attempt?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you don't need any well-ordering principle for this at all if you already know that numbers can be represented in base $2$: For any integer $0\le a<2^{m+1}$, I can write $a=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k\cdot 2^k$ where $a_k\in\{0,1\}$. Hence, I can pick all the envelopes whose index $k$ satisfies $a_k=1$, and their contents will sum to $a$. Then again, the point of this exercise may also be to prove that representation in base $2$ is possible ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.